# VLC mediaplayer : Fast forward/backward are not working with the shortcut keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player

I use the `3.0.10` latest VLC Media player. I am not able to skip forward or backward using the shortcut keys(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>). If I try the shortcut keys, this make the video to start from the beginning again.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using alt/grp to the right of the space bar? That will by default make a much larger jump.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I tried the keys of left and right of space bar and same behavior.  One thing I noticed is that , this happens with a ```mpg``` video file.

Comment: Try clearing the prefs. You can do it if you re-install, but I think there should be an option somewhere inside the prefs themselves. [I'm not on Windows so can't check where it is]

Comment: @Tetsujin , Tried that , it didn't help.

Comment: Then you have something else interfering… & you need to figure out what it might be.

Answer (score 2):

I had to disable `Fast Seek` in the `Input/Codecs -> Playback control` section (or under `Codecs` in simple mode) **and** restart VLC; otherwise, it would often fail to skip forward or backward.

Comment: This solved my short jump problem, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- In VLC, open *Tools | Prefernces*.
- Click *Show Settings | All*.
- In the *Advanced Preferences* settings,select *Interface | Hotkey settings*.
- Scroll to *Short backwards jump* and *Short forward jump*, check the settings and test them.
- If for some reason you can't make them work with the defaults, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd>, try using a different key combination.

[image: VLC - Set Hotkeys]

Answer (score 0):

If the VLC player version you are currently using automatically shoots back to the beginning of your video when you attempt to drag or fast-forward through it, try installing an earlier version. Just remember to uninstall your problematic version beforehand.

I had such issues when trying to fast-forward through .avi files so I installed my original VLC version 2.2.1 which has since always worked for me without such glitches.

CAUTION: prevent your functioning VLC version from automatically updating by clicking on Tools, Preferences, and UNCHECKING the box "Activate Updates Notifier".